# How to update Galaxy S4 GT-I9505 from Lollipop to Nougat Android 7.0 version?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, 7.0-nougat

How to update the Galaxy S4 GT-I9505 from Android 5.0 Lollipop to Android 7.0 Nougat (without Root)? Currently not getting or not showing any updates either with Software Update or from Samsung Smart Switch/Samsung Kies in Galaxy S4 device.

Additionally, I do not see Android 7.0 Nougat version updates in SamMobile website with respective to the firmware.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply not available, and likely will not be due to S4's age (3+ years - most manufacturers won't support beyond 2). See how it doesn't even get Marshmallow yet?

There is much 3rd-party development for the device, however, and [an AOSP-based Nougat ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4/i9505-orig-develop/jdcteam-android-source-project-nrd90m-t3453084) is available. You do need to dive into the world of flashing custom ROMs (*) which could take some time, there will be bugs in the beginning, and you will lose many Samsung-specific features should you decide to do the switch, but it's the only way out if you want to stay on the cutting edge.

*: On Samsung devices, flashing a custom ROM usually doesn't require root, but custom ROMs often come with root.

Comment: http://www.resurrectionremix.com/ is currently on Android 6, based on CyanogenMod, and I imagine they'll take it up to Android 7 at some point.

Comment: @Tim AOSP is the base for all else. When AOSP is near perfect, CM/Omni will follow suit, then RR/AICP/etc. which are based on one of the two.

Comment: Yep agreed, I was just pointing out a ROM that generally works well.